# How to use Case when Then Select statement in Sql-Server

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone help me to write this conditions using case when then.

```
SELECT CASE
 WHEN D.AppEmployeeID = D.ByEmployeeID AND D.CommentStatus = 'A' THEN D.CreatedOn, E.FirstName, E.LastName, D.Remarks, D.Attachment
 WHEN D.AppEmployeeID <> D.ByEmployeeID AND D.CommentStatus = 'R' THEN D.CreatedOn, E.FirstName, E.LastName, D.Remarks, D.Attachment
FROM tbl_Conversation_History D
INNER JOIN tbl_Employee_Master E on D.ByEmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
WHERE D.AppEmployeeID = @EmployeeID AND D.ByEmployeeID IN (@EmployeeID, @ReportingMg, @DelegatedMgr) AND SubAppraisalID=@SubAppraisalID 
AND D.Attachment IS NULL
ORDER BY D.CreatedOn DESC
```

Comment: Why not just use `IF`?

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression*. It has to return a scalar value. Not an arbitrary (part of) a statement/parse tree. It's not clear what you're trying to do here since so far as I can see, both `THEN`s list the exact same columns. It's also unclear what you'd expect to happen if neither `WHEN` was true. You can't change the "shape" of a query's result set - the number of columns, their names and types. At the moment it looks like you're trying to write a query that returns 0 or five columns, and that decision varies on a per-row basis, which makes no sense.

Comment: Also both the `then` statements are same

Comment: but if how to use in this kind of statement

Comment: You need to explain *what you're trying to do*. Some sample data and expected results would help a lot. The problem with the question as asked is that you're expecting us to understand your *intentions* from a broken query, and you *assume* that `CASE` is part of the solution, which I'd guess it will not be.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- `CASE WHEN` should always end with `END` (after the last `WHEN`, or after `ELSE` if present).
- `CASE WHEN` can only return a single value after each `WHEN` (and also after `ELSE` if present). Multiple values is not allowed.

So if you want 5 columns to depend on those same conditions, then you'll need to repeat the `CASE WHEN` clause 5 times (once for each column)... or perhaps put the conditions somewhere else, e.g. in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your table structure. As per my understanding you are missing the `END` statement in your query. For an example have a look on the below query for how to use CASE WHEN statement.

```
CREATE TABLE tempTable(Id int, Price int)

INSERT INTO tempTable VALUES(1,500)
INSERT INTO tempTable VALUES(1,1500)
INSERT INTO tempTable VALUES(1,2500)
INSERT INTO tempTable VALUES(1,3500)

SELECT
CASE
WHEN Price > 2000 THEN 'Over Priced'
WHEN Price > 1000 THEN 'Perfectly Priced'
ELSE 'Offer'
END as PriceRange
FROM tempTable
```